# Use document.getElementById in the src of script tag

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to use document.getElementById in the src of script tag
like this:

```
<div id="testTracking">

<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript" src="https://test.com/tracking/hio_wm.js?state="+document.getElementById("state").value+ "&zip=" +document.getElementById("zipcode").value+ ""></script>


</div>
```

Can it is possible to use `document.getElementById` tags within SRC attribute of Script tag .

If No then plz suggest how it can be possible .

Thanks

Comment: thats not possible. which goal you want to reach ?

Comment: The `src` attribute is not interpreted by JavaScript, so no, it is not possible this way.

Comment: why you need to do this ? sorry but this makes no sense.

Comment: I think it makes perfect sense that browsers don't interpret JS inside random attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, you can do it with document.write but you have to make sure that the DOM is already fully loaded. You can use jQuery for that.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $().ready(function() 
     {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.com/tracking/hio_wm.js?state='+document.getElementById("state").value+ '&zip=' +document.getElementById("zipcode").value + '></script>');
     });
</script>
```

Comment: `document.write` inside a ready handler doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: for me the whole thing of inserting dynamically js files is an good idea, as i told before.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://test.com/tracking/hio_wm.js?state='+document.getElementById("state").value+ '&zip=' +document.getElementById("zipcode").value + '"></script>');

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create it dynamically :

```
var ss = document.createElement('script');
ss.src = "https://test.com/tracking/hio_wm.js?state="
    +document.getElementById("state").value+ "&zip="    
    +document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="testTracking">  
    <script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript" src="https://test.com/tracking/hio_wm.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
        var zip = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
        initializeData(state, zip)
    </script>
</div>
```

And the in hio_wm.js:

```
function initializeData( state, zipcode )
{
    //do whatever you need with that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you put values in your `state` and `zipcode` elements on the server side. E.g., in asp.net:

```
<input type="text" value="<%: Model.State %>" id="state" />
<input type="text" value="<%: Model.Zip %>" id="zipcode" />
```

If so, you can do it this way:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript" src="https://test.com/tracking/hio_wm.js?state=<%: Model.State%>&zip=<%:Model.Zip%>"></script>
```